# Eclipse RCP How to fix "Missing Constraint: Import-Package:" and "Require-Bundle"

Tags: java, eclipse, osgi, eclipse-rcp

I'm actually learning OSGI with Eclipse RCP. I'm created a plugin ProJet and a run configuration adding frameworks plugins as on the following image:
[image]

While trying to run my OSGI application, I'm getting the following validations errors:
[image]

Do someone know how to fix this error?

Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: Hit the _Select Required_ button. If this does not work, you have to add them to your target platform first.

Comment: You have to include all  the required bundles in your run configuration - this will usually be a lot more than you have shown. Or use a Feature based RCP when you just need to list a few features.

Comment: Thanks @howlger
It worked after hitting the "Select required" Button.

Thans so much.